# how to move website created with xampp(windows) to hosting server

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, xampp

I am new to this hosting stuff. I dono anything about hosting a site. 
I am developing a website in xampp-windows. What should i do for hosting the website in a domain. If u know please tell me about this hosting of a site in my case.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get yourself a simple host provider that gives you roughly the same versions for PHP and MYSQL as your current home install. For starters, choose a shared host with plesk or something simple like that. Make sure you're getting phpmyadmin if you're used to that.
2. export your database and move it to your host (import)
3. Go over your code and check for windows-only references. The first things that come to mind are paths (c:\yourpath\www\yoursite\ versus /var/www/yoursite/ for isntance)
4. Put your code on the site.
5. test. If you find problems, go to stap 3. If you don't, go to step 6)
6. ...
7. profit!

Comment: thanks a lot nanne. one more doubt(dont mind if it was silly) : if my hosting server was using linux or something other than windows vista(my pc) and if it is having apache , php & mysql installed seperately(simply not xampp) , then what should i do for this either in code or apart from code

Comment: Above is (also) directed at a linux host using that setup. The biggest change you at least need to do is look at the paths in your code (as I mentioned in step 3). Obviously you should change your db-settings too, reflecting the new user/password, but possibly leaving a current reference to "localhost". There shouldn't be too many other problems. (xampp or 'seperate' isn't really an issue)

Comment: really thanks a lot lot nanne. this is the first time i am hearing something valuable about hosting stuff

Comment: No problem. In the end you might find some problems in step 5 and need to fix them, but that's not anything I could find for you ;). Good luck