# Hosting a website created with xampp

Tags: php, web, xampp, host

I have spent some time designing a wordpress/phpbb site, and hosting it on localhost using xampp.  I would like to soon host my website on a real domain, but I am not sure what I would have to do and change in order to make it a success.  Is it possible to just use the files I have placed in htdocs inside the xampp directory?

Thanks for your help, and sorry if my question is confusing or badly explained.

Comment: [move website created with xampp(windows) to hosting server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723706/how-to-move-website-created-with-xamppwindows-to-hosting-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, that's the point of XAMPP - website prototyping. I assume that by *real domain* you mean a hosting service. If you also use MySQL make sure you copy all data to the new database and check PHP dependencies with the new host.

Comment: another note is that wordpress is annoying about storing full urls in any of the data that is configured there is tool changing all urls from old domain to new domain http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: I plan on using something like bluehost or hostgator, will I be easy to transfer everything once I get hosting service?